# How to limit the count of the parallel http requests in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script which I start a several http requests inside a loop
Let's say that I have to make 1000 http requests.

The thing is that I can do only one http request per IP and I have only 10 IPs.

So, after 10 parallel requests, I have to wait a response to make another one.

How do I wait without block the script one response from a http request to start another one?

My problem is if I execute a while waiting for a free IP my whole script is blocked and I do not receive any response.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module for this.

You can use `async#eachLimit` to limit the concurrent requests to 10.

```
var urls = [
  // a list of 100 urls
];

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
  /* make a http request */
  callback(); // when done, callback
}

async.eachLimit(urls, 10, makeRequest, function(err) {
  if(err) throw err;
});
```

This code will loop through the list of urls and call `makeRequest` for each one.  It will stop at 10 concurrent requests and will not proceed with the 11th request until one of the first 10 have finished.